# How to access parent class integer variable in child class?

Tags: java

I am trying to access int a= 10 variable in child class but getting error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field FreshJuice.a

Following is my code.

```
class FreshJuice {
    enum FreshJuiceSize{SMALL,MEDIUM,LARGE};
    FreshJuiceSize size;
    int a   =   10;
}

public class Index extends FreshJuice {

    enum programmingLanguage{PHP,Java,Dotnet,HTML};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println(FreshJuice.FreshJuiceSize.SMALL);
        System.out.println(programmingLanguage.PHP);
        System.out.println(FreshJuice.a); //getting error in this line
    }

}
```

I want to directly access int variable of FreshJuice class in child class. How can i achieve this target?

Comment: Why are you being abstract and secretive? You got an error. Tell us **exactly** what error you got. But, before you do that, check that others haven't had the same error. (Hint: they have.)

Comment: You need an instance of the class. It's not static.

Comment: I am getting error Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field FreshJuice.a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an instance of FreshJuice class:

`FreshJuice fj = new FreshJuice();`

Now you can access the variable `a` .

But if you set your variable as `private int a=10;`  Then you can't access that  still. That's why it is good practice to use getter and setter methods to access those private variables.